# Troubling with installing firebase-tools

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

After installing node and the npm, I tried installing firebase-tools on my computer (because cloud functions). This is what I see:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/joeljohnson/.npm/_logs/2018-01-26T16_56_29_829Z-debug.log
```

I haven't found a solution to my problem yet, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you need to run the installation command with `sudo` to gain permission to write to the location it's talking about?

Comment: I tried adding sudo, I get a series of error messages: EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp/8.9.4"

Comment: You might want to consider installing node differently.  Maybe use nvm to install a copy in your home directory where you have full write access.

Comment: That seemed to help, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this. The problem is with the package 'grpc'. I don't know the exact nature of error but through trial and error i moved to the the directory where firebase was installed and installed grpc manually.
Commands for that are.

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools #This will give errors but let it be
cd /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/
sudo npm install grpc@1.4.1
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```